# Delete all files and folders in /tmp older than a day

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to delete all files and folders in the `/tmp` dir that are older than a day.

I know to delete all the files and folders I have to do

```
rm -rf *
```

But I'm unsure how else I find all the files and folders older than a day to delete those and put the cron in.

Comment: Be VERY careful with that command. If you are in the wrong directory *cough* / *cough*, you could inadvertently remove files you didn't want to remove.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, use `find` to select these files:

```
find /tmp -mmin +1440
```

will find files that were modified more than 1440 minutes ago. (There is an option to use days instead of minutes, but it rounds upwards and +1 will mean 2 days or more, unfortunately. See notice below).

Try this, and if you are satisfied that this finds the right files, delete them in one go:

```
find /tmp -mmin +1440 -delete
```

See `man find` for other possibilities (last status changed time, access time).

---

**Notice on the usage of `-mtime +1`:**

> In [man find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/find.1.html)
>
> **It says:**
>
> **-mtime n**
>
> File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.
>
> **But it also says:**
>
> See the comments for `-atime` to understand how rounding affects the
>   interpretation of file modification times.
>
> **The comments for `-atime` say:**
>
> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last
>   accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match **-atime +1**, a
>   file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

In other words,  `-mtime` can count only in units of 24 hours or one day each so as far as  `-mtime +1` goes, this means exactly more than one day by at least one day ( ie. two days+ )

`-mmin` on the other hand can count in minutes. So, if strict accuracy is vital, then `-mmin +1440` ( 1440 minutes = 1 day ) could be used instead of `-mtime +1`

Comment: @Raffa I have done so. Thank you for being cooperative!